# Change div position relative top left dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change a divs position (top, left) when I hover over a LI. Here's what i'm using, it seems to set the position:relative but it does not add or change the top or left elements.

It gets the XX and YY values from this html:

```
<li value="9" xx="10" yy="10"><a href="#">Content Here</a></li>


$(function(){
    $("div.listcol ul li").bind("mouseover",function(){
        $("div.cutaway-text").hide();    
        $("div.cutaway-image img").hide();
        $("div.cutaway-image img#img"+this.value).show();
        var top2 = 0;
        var left2 = 0;

        top2 = $(this).attr('xx');
        left2 = $(this).attr('yy');

        $(".highlighter").css('position', 'relative');
        $(".highlighter").css('top', top2); 
        $(".highlighter").css('left', left2); 

        //var d = document.getElementById('highlighter');
        //d.style.position = "absolute";
        //d.style.left = left;
        //d.style.top = top;

        //document.getElementById("div.highlighter").style.left = left2;
        //document.getElementById("div.highlighter").style.top = top2;
        //console.log(this.value);
    });
});
```

The commented out lines are what I have tried/played about with already, thanks.

Edit: here's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SWXgb/

Comment: provide your html, please
What stands behind "xx" and 'yy' attr?

Comment: have you inspected value of top2 and left2?

Comment: what's inside 'top2' and 'left2' before you set it?

Comment: Put your code and html in jsfiddle.

Comment: yeah it pulls the xx and yy values from the LI no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'px' to your `top` and `left` values like this:

```
$('.highlighter').css({  top : top2 + 'px', left : left2 + 'px' });
```

See [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/SWXgb/4/).

Comment: thanks! schoolboy error :/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SWXgb/6/

Things I noticed:

- Your first `<li>` tag doesn't have an `xx` attribute, it has `top` instead.
- You hadn't specified 'px' or 'em' values to qualify the `top` and `left` values in your JavaScript.
- The child div (with class *highlighter*) was set to `position: relative`, if you want it to be positioned in relation to the parent div, you'll need `position: relative` on the *rollover-image*, and `position: absolute` on the child.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have an idea.

CSS: top, left, right and bottom are just working, if position is 'absolute'...
Use margin-top, margin-left, margin-right and margin-bottom when position is relative.

Or, make the parent-container to position relative, to have the absolute position starting at the first relative-parent ;)